# Azure DevOps: How can I nest YML template within YML template when both are defined as resource

Tags: templates, azure-devops, nested, yaml, azure-pipelines

The following example fails with an error. Keyword "resources" is not allowed in nested templates. "buildAndPackage.yml" cannot declare "resources".

pipeline.yml:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: templateLibrary/pipeline

stages:

- template: buildAndPackage.yml@templates
  parameters:
  - projectName: 'myProject'
```

buildAndPackage.yml in templateLibrary/pipeline repo:

```
parameters:
- name: projectName
  default: ''

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: templateLibrary/pipeline

stages:
- stage: Build_${{ parameters.projectName }}
  jobs:

  - template: build.yml@templates
    parameters:
    - projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}

  - template: package.yml@templates
    parameters:
    - projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}
```

build.yml in templateLibrary/pipeline repo:

```
parameters:
- name: projectName
  default: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a simpler, cleaner way. If the nested template (`build.yml`) is located in the same repository as the main one (`buildAndPackage.yml`), you can just use relative paths to reference it:

```yaml
# buildAndPackage.yml

parameters:
- name: projectName
  default: ''

stages:
- stage: Build_${{ parameters.projectName }}
  jobs:

  - template: build.yml
    parameters:
    - projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}

  - template: package.yml
    parameters:
    - projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew the answer before asking the question here, I just wanted to share the solution. The template that was not resolved in nested template can be, instead, resolved in pipeline.yml and passed as a parameter.
This is not a clean solution as it breaks "separation of concern" principle in Onion Architecture, but at least it solves the issue.

pipeline.yml:

```
...

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: templateLibrary/pipeline

stages:

- template: buildAndPackage.yml@templates
  parameters:
  - projectName: 'myProject'
  - buildYml: build.yml@templates
  - packageYml: package.yml@templates
```

buildAndPackage.yml in templateLibrary/pipeline repo:

```
parameters:
- name: projectName
  default: ''
- name: buildYml
  type: object
- name: packageYml
  type: object

stages:
- stage: Build_${{ parameters.projectName }}
  jobs:

  - template: ${{ parameters.buildYml }}
    parameters:
    - projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}

  - template: ${{ parameters.packageYml }}
    parameters:
    - projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}
```

build.yml in templateLibrary/pipeline repo:

```
parameters:
- name: projectName
  default: ''
```